# Firestore batch update - check if doc exists

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I try to update documents using batch. It is OK if they exists but if not I have error. I would like to "set" if doc does not exists

```
var batch = db.batch();

            $.each(newProductsArray, function (key, value) {
                if (value['sku']) {
                    console.log(value['sku']);
                    var sku = value['sku'];
                    var name = value['name']
                    docRef = db_user.collection("products").doc(sku);

                    batch.update(docRef, {
                        productSKU: sku + "sku",
                        productName: name

                    });

                }

            });

            // Commit the batch
            batch.commit().then(function () {
                ...
                )
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch.html#set) instead of update(), telling it to [merge](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SetOptions.html#optional-merge) fields if the document already exists.

```
batch.set(docRef, { ... }, { merge: true });
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the case where you want to set a property like `createdDate` only the first time you create the document, and if the document already exists you only want to update the other properties. Let me know if you have any ideas for how to achieve that.

Comment: @TimTrewartha Why don't you post a new question describing in more detail what the problem is and what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Thanks! I made a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73934101/best-way-to-batch-create-if-not-exists-in-firestore