# Best way to batch create if not exists in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with a project where we create a bunch of entries in firestore based on results from an API endpoint we do not control, using a firestore cloud function. The API endpoint returns ids which we use for the document ids, but it does not include any timestamp information. Since we want to include a `createdDate` in our documents, we are using `admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()` to set the timestamp of the document.
On subsequent runs of the function, some of the documents will already exist so if we use `batch.commit` with `create`, it will fail since some of the documents exist. However, if we use `batch.commit` with `update`, we will either not be able to include a timestamp, or the current timestamp will be overwritten. As a final requirement, we do update these documents from a web application and set some properties like a state, so we can't limit the permissions on the documents to disallow update completely.

What would be the best way to achieve this?
I am currently using `.create` and have removed the `batch`, but I feel like this is less performant, and I occasionally do get the error `Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` on the firestore function.

First prize would be a `batch` that can create or update the documents, but does not edit the `createdDate` field. I'm also hoping to avoid reading the documents first to save a read, but I'd be happy to add it in if it's the best solution.
Thanks!

Current code is something like this:

```
  const createDocPromise = docRef
    .create(newDoc)
    .then(() => {
      // success, do nothing
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (
        err.details &&
        err.details.includes('Document already exists')
      ) {
        // doc already exists, ignore error
      } else {
        console.error(`Error creating doc`, err);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This might not be possible with batched writes as `set()` will overwrite the existing document, `update()` will update the timestamp and `create()` will throw an error as you've mentioned. One workaround would be to use `create()` for each document with [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) that won't run `catch()` if any of the promise fails.

```js
const results = [] // results from the API

const promises = results.map((r) => db.doc(`col/${r.id}`).create(r));

const newDocs = await Promise.allSettled(promises)

// either "fulfilled" or "rejected"
newDocs.forEach((result) => console.log(result.status))
```

If any documents exists already, `create()` will throw an error and `status` for that should be `rejected`. This way you won't have to read the document at first place.

---

Alternatively, you could store all the IDs in a single document or RTDB and filter out duplicates (this should only cost 1 read per invocation) and then add the data.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with `Promise.all`, I didn't know that `Promise.allSettled` existed but not I see I can use it if I target `ES2020`. I think it would make sense to make that change.
Do you know how the performance of this compares to if you use a transaction or batch? I would imagine it is slower without a batch.

Comment: @TimTrewartha yes, batched writes would be a bit faster than individually updating each document but that should it shouldn't be noticeable given that a batched write also has a max limit of 500 per batch.

Answer (score 0):

Since you prefer to keep the batch and you want to avoid reading the documents, a possible solution would be to store the timestamps in a field of type Array. So, you don't overwrite the `createdDate` field but save all the values corresponding to the different writes.

This way, when you read one of the documents you sort this array and take the oldest value: it is the very first timestamp that was saved and corresponds to the document creation.

This way you don't need any extra writes or extra reads.

Comment: I see, that option did cross my mind. Would you use a sentinel to push to the array? Could you still order on that field if it is an array? Our frontend application currently sorts the entries by `createdDate` descending

Comment: Yes you can use `FieldValue.arrayUnion` to push to the Array. And you can, in the same Cloud Function, set the value of a single field that you will use for sorting if and only if the Array has one element (the first element being the creation date).